# Create file from Document(xml) in Android

Tags: android, file, dom, android-asynctask, outputstream

I am a beginner of android. I try to write the file form the xml that is on the website.
I do not know how to do it, I try to use AsyncTask but my code is error and I think it was not true, so I would like to ask you about this. Thank you very musch.

Comment: there is more information about your problem in the tags of the question than the question itself.

Comment: What are the data on the website ? What are the data on your device ? What do you have as an input and what do you want as an output ? Could you be a bit more specific and show us a bit of your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for [Uploading Files](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

You probabaly don't need asynctask if your xml is not every big